# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} = 2^n$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k} {n\choose k}=0$ for $n \ge 1$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} = 2^n$  and  $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k} {n\choose k}=0$
how to prove this statement holds for any $n \ge  1$ ?

I am not sure how this released to $(x+y)^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
(x+y)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} x^i y^{n-k}
\end{align}
Plugging in $x = y = 1$ gives
\begin{align}
2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}
\end{align}
The second follows from $x = 1$ and $y = -1$, which gives
\begin{align}
0 = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-1)^i
\end{align}